# How to construct `TxOutRef`?

Tags: nft, policy, mint, mintingpolicy

I am building an NFT minting policy which takes an argument of type `TxOutRef` as parameter. To this when I pass my parameter, it doesn't match with what is actually given in the transaction. Here is my policy: [image: My policy code]

Suppose my `tx-in` (in context of `cardano-cli`) is `bccdfb39bcf97b9bc499ef19c02f33c64df1d7e68cfcff7f65a737c9c6ce4224#0`. Then this is how I am passing it to compiler: [image: passing TxOutRef]

I tried comparing what I passed with what is actually received in my `mkPolicy` but surprisingly, if I remove out `firstInput`, it is able to print my error message, else with `firstInput` being present, I get the following in my console: [image: error by firstInput]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following suggestion from [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/issues/4282#issuecomment-992130598), I got it working by doing following modification: [image: TxOutRef Construction]

As `TxId` has an instance for `IsString` derived via `LegerBytes`. In particular, [this](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/4904/7049) answer is also helpful.